# Playing in-built webcam feed in a UWP app stopped working after?

Tags: c#, uwp, mediacapture

I'm trying to play the built-in webcam feed in a `MediaElement` within a UWP app. It works fine for a few users but there is no feed played for most and I'm lost on what could be the issue.

Some observations when the webcam feed doesn't play:

- The code executes without any exceptions
- The dialog that requests user permission to access the camera is shown
- The LED indicating the webcam is in use turns on soon as it is executed, but there is no feed.
- Skype and Camera apps work fine.
- The app was working as expected until a week back. A few things that changed in the mean time that could have had an impact are

  - Installed Kaspersky
  - A bunch of windows updates
  - Uninstalled VS2017 professional edition & VS2019 Community edition and installed VS2019 Professional Edition

Some additional information that might be needed to narrow down the reason.

- Webcam is enabled in the Package manifest of the app
- App Target version: 18362
- App Min version: 18362
- Windows OS Version : 18362

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks much in advance!

Here is the piece of code used to play the webcam feed where VideoStreamer is a `MediaElement`.

```
private async Task PlayLiveVideo()
    {
        var allGroups = await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync();
        var eligibleGroups = allGroups.Select(g => new
        {
            Group = g,

            // For each source kind, find the source which offers that kind of media frame,
            // or null if there is no such source.
            SourceInfos = new MediaFrameSourceInfo[]
            {
    g.SourceInfos.FirstOrDefault(info => info.DeviceInformation?.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front
        && info.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Color),
    g.SourceInfos.FirstOrDefault(info => info.DeviceInformation?.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back
        && info.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Color)
            }
        }).Where(g => g.SourceInfos.Any(info => info != null)).ToList();

        if (eligibleGroups.Count == 0)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No source group with front and back-facing camera found.");
            return;
        }

        var selectedGroupIndex = 0; // Select the first eligible group
        MediaFrameSourceGroup selectedGroup = eligibleGroups[selectedGroupIndex].Group;
        MediaFrameSourceInfo frontSourceInfo = selectedGroup.SourceInfos[0];
        
        MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();    
        MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
        {
            SourceGroup = selectedGroup,
            SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.ExclusiveControl,
            MemoryPreference = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Cpu,
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video, 
        };
        try
        {
            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MediaCapture initialization failed: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        } 
        var frameMediaSource1 = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaFrameSource(mediaCapture.FrameSources[frontSourceInfo.Id]);               
        VideoStreamer.SetPlaybackSource(frameMediaSource1);
        VideoStreamer.Play();
    }
```

Comment: I have replied to you on [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/30071/playing-in-built-webcam-feed-in-a-uwp-app-stopped.html), you can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Faywang-MSFT [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/30822/view.html) , it worked after marking the application as trusted in Kaspersky.